# Best way to implement HTTPS for API hosted on AWS ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, https, fastapi

First of all, I'm in no way an expert at security or networking, so any advice would be appreciated.
I'm developing an IOS app that communicates with an API hosted on an AWS EC2 linux machine.
The API is deployed using **FastAPI + Docker**.
Currently, I'm able to communicate with my remote API using HTTP requests to my server's public IP address (after opening port 80 for TCP) and transfer data between the client and my server.

One of my app's features requires sending a private cookie from the client to the server.
Since having the cookie allows potential attackers to make requests on behalf of the client, I intend to transfer the cookie securely with HTTPS.

I have several questions:

1. Will implementing HTTPS for my server solve my security issue? Is that the right approach?
2. The [FastAPI "Deploy with Docker" docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/) recommend [this](https://medium.com/@tiangolo/docker-swarm-mode-and-traefik-for-a-https-cluster-20328dba6232) article for implementing TLS for the server (using Docker Swarm Mode and Traefik).
   Is that guide relevant for my use-case?
3. In that article, it says `Define a server name using a subdomain of a domain you own`. 
   Do I **really** need to own a domain to implement HTTPS? Can't I just keep using the server's IP address to communicate with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will implementing HTTPS for my server solve my security issue? Is that the right approach?

With HTTP all traffic between your clients and the ec2 is in **plain text**. With HTTPS the traffic is encrypted, so it is secure.

> FastAPI "Deploy with Docker"

Sadly can't comment on the article.

> Do I really need to own a domain to implement HTTPS?

Yes. The SSL certificates can only be registered for domains that you own. You can't get the certificate for domain that is not yours.

Comment: Cool. I still don’t get it though - why do I need a domain? I don't actually want a website, just a way to send requests to my server’s IP...

Comment: @UriYakir Because to have valid public SSL certificate for HTTPS domain is required as SSL binds to a domain, not an IP address. You can use self-signed SSL certificate if you want without a domian, but you will get warning from every browser that the connection is insecure.